# Regarding Pixel Art Maker toggle () and remove ()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help regarding Pixel Art Maker.
where I added two extra features `toggle ()` and `remove ()` .
The problem is, when I insert numbers to draw grid, and click `submit` button, in `first attempt` , it draw the grid.  But after clicking the toggle button or remove button , in my `second attempt` to draw grid, the `submit` button doesn't work and I can't able to draw grid.

Here is the link.
https://codepen.io/sofianayak55/pen/dKEaPw

Please go through this link, avoid the styling part, I will do it later Kindly go through the JavaScript and  jQuery section.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stacoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and than ask questions.

Comment: Pressing clear *removes* the canvas element permanently. Toggle hides it, so the Submit actually works as expected, but you need to click the toggle button again to actually display the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your remove function.

```
$(".clearGrid" ).click(function() {
    $("#pixelCanvas").html("");
});
```

You have used `$("#pixelCanvas").remove()` which is actually removing `#pixelCanvas` table. So next time it is not getting bind. You just need to clear only its html part.

Comment: Thank you so much @Karan. Now it's working properly.